# Expected constant expression, cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to create an object array and it works just fine if I enter the array size manually, but whenever it tries to get the infromation from the function args it gives the errors "Expected constant expression" and "cannot allocate an array of constant size 0".

I've searched around and found multiple solutions but none of them works for me. Code currently looks like this:

```
Array::Array(int in, int min, int max) 
{
    size = in;
    Heltal *htal[size];
}
```

The size integer and htal object is defined in the header file.

The line that seems to be causing the problem is the last one.
Whats causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VLAs (variable length arrays) are not supported in C++. Even if they were, `a` is a `vector` so `Heltal *htal[a];` doesn't make sense.

You fix this by using an `std::vector` instead of an array (of a valid size):

```
std::vector<Heltal*> htal(a.size() /*or whatever size you want*/);
```

Comment: The vector part was a fix I tried that was stated on a website. If I for example exchange the a in htal for 5 it works just fine. I just don't know how to get it to accept the in parameter. I updated my main post to show you what the original looked like.

Comment: Krall, the Web site that suggested using vector surely meant that you should use the vector *instead of the array*, **not** that you should use the vector to *specify the size* of the array. And this answer demonstrates exactly what the Web site meant.

Comment: OP clearly has some misunderstanding of basic C/C++ concepts. Telling him to use `std::vector` is a dangerous advice IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an array has to be a compile-time constant, and `size` isn't a constant. You'll need to dynamically allocate the array instead:

```
std::vector<Heltal *> htal(size);
```